# Error in running Python script that import Numpy in C program

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, numpy, compiler-errors

I'm trying to run the Python script in the C program, here is the code:

```
#include <Python.h>
int main(void) 
{
   char filename[MAX_STRING_LENGTH] = "example.py";
   FILE* fp;
   Py_Initialize();
   fp = _Py_fopen(filename, "r");
   PyRun_SimpleFile(fp, filename);
   Py_Finalize();
   return 0;
}
```

Here is the code in *example.py*

```
import numpy as np
```

When I ran the C code in Visual Studio Community 2019, it returns that it could not find `numpy.core._multiarray_umath`. This is the error message that I got from the run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 150, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.9 from "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\example.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.21.1"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

I tried to uninstall and reinstall Numpy a couple of times but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: In windows, you need to add the file path to the numpy module in a `environment variable.`. [This](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/02/25/install-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-python-3-windows/) guide might help.

Comment: It didn't work. It still returns the same error.

Comment: If you open a command prompt cmd.exe, can you do `start example.py` ? You may need to properly set up the module search path with `Py_SetPath`

Comment: @mattip it works if I just run the Python script file itself. But it returns errors if I run the Python script in the C program.